# ts2322 "is not assignable to type never" error in simpliest case

Tags: typescript

I've been reading several similar topics but they all about some particular cases and i get this error in a simpliest posiible case. What is generally point of this error and how to solve it?

```
type SomeInterface = {
  prop1: number
  prop2: boolean
}

const testFn = (obj: SomeInterface, key: keyof SomeInterface, value: any) => {
  obj[key] = value
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

One more thing should be aware of is `obj[key]` with `key` is `keyof SometInterface` would always return `never` type which isn't assigned even `any` type.

#### Solution

You might know this is quite common use case which can resolve by using generic type:

```js
const testFn = <T extends SomeInterface, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K, value: T[K]) => {
  obj[key] = value
}
```

But if you wish not to use generic type, you can set the `value` type as `never`:

```js
const testFn = (obj: SomeInterface, key: keyof SomeInterface, value: never) => {
  obj[key] = value;
}
```

Comment: No problems with generics, it looks more typesafe than using never, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue might by that `obj[key]` is either `number` or `boolean`, and since there is no overlap between these two types, it effectively becomes `never`.

This is one way this might be fixed, using a generic:

```js
const testFn  = function<T extends keyof SomeInterface>(obj: SomeInterface, key: T, value: SomeInterface[T]) {
  obj[key] = value
}
```

We're basically saying that `T` is a keyof `SometInterface`, that needs to be passed as the second argument.

But we're also saying that the third argument (value) must match the type of the key of `SomeInterface`.